# Is there a python tensorflow/pytorch function like the x.toPixels tensorflowjs function?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow.js

I need a replacement for the `tf.browser.toPixels() tensorflowJS` function. Trying to port some code to python and I'm wondering if there is a quick way around this.

In the browser this gets really simple and we just callback new frames and draw into a canvas. But in python development, say in `matplotlib` or `tkinter`, I guess I'm gonna need some tricks.

Is there a (not super big) solution for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let say you are having a 2D tensor `img` which run it in your browser like `tf.browser.toPixels(img)`. You can draw similar images using `OpenCV` and `matplotlib` like:

- Using Pytorch

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# If your data is in GPU:
img_np = img.cpu().numpy()

# Using OpenCV
cv2.imwrite(img_np.astype(np.uint8), "image.png")

# Using matplotlib
plt.imshow(img_np)
```

- Tensorflow

````py
```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img_np = img.numpy()

# Using OpenCV
cv2.imwrite(img_np.astype(np.uint8), "image.png")

# Using matplotlib
plt.imshow(img_np)
````

Also, if you have a 3D tensor ( i.e. `n x m x 3`) you can still average the bands and make a 2D tensor out of it and plot them the same way.

Comment: Thank you! I wonder, is it possible without writing it to .png file?